# Mac SpriteKit - Can't create texture atlas at compile time

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, sktextureatlas

I've been using SpriteKit for a while in iOS; now I'm developing an app for the Mac.

I've setup a texture atlas as usual:

1. Enable texture atlas generation for **both the Project and the Target** (I started from the "Document Based Application" template, not "SpriteKit Game". It has different build settings).
2. Drag all the individual texture image files into a folder,
3. Rename the folder to *"Something.atlas"*,
4. Add the folder to the project,
5. At runtime, create the atlas by name (i.e., `[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Something"];`).
6. Obtain individual "textures" by name (i.e., `[_atlas textureNamed:@"MyTexture"];`) and create `SKSpriteNode` instances with them.

I am preloading the atlas asynchronously, but the completion handler never gets called (see comments):

```
_atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Something"];

        if (!_atlas) {
            NSLog(@"Error: Failed to create atlas!");
            // This line doesn't execute, so atlas is not nil.
        }

        [_atlas preloadWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
            // This block doesn't get executed either, 
            // so atlas loading somehow fails...

            NSLog(@"Atlas Loaded!");

            [self createSprites];
        }];
```

When I check the package contents of the build product (e.g., *MyApp.app*), in the resources subdirectory I can see the atlas folder (*"Something.atlasc"*), but it only contains **a .plist file with no entries**, and the image resources are nowhere to be found... So what gives?

Comment: Off topic, but... perhaps `self` inside the block isn't a good idea?

Comment: is the .atlas a folder reference? In xcode the folder should have a blue icon rather than a yellow icon, and it must be in a group (folder with yellow icon) or the project's root

Comment: Yes, it is. After some testing, it turned out the problem is with the **workspace** (yes, you heard that right). The same projects, when built from a different workspace, work fine. ANY project opened or created within this workspace, will export the broken atlas...

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to Apple (17076217), with the workspace file and a couple of projects (which include the atlas) as an attachment.

Comment: Actually, there seems to be no way of importing an .atlas folder as a "yellow icon" into Xcode: Regardless which radio button you chose, it is always exported as a blue icon (folder reference), and Target Membership applies only to the folder as a whole (not the individual files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it wasn't the workspace after all. The same workspace/project, when copied to the Desktop, builds fine.

The cause seems to be that, one of the intermediate directories in the path to the project folder had a name in japanese characters. I tested as follows:

1. Change folder name to english -> clean build folder -> build -> OK
2. Change folder name back to japanese -> clean build folder -> build -> Atlas broken
3. Change folder name back to english -> clean build folder -> build -> OK

*...(you see the pattern)...*

I wonder **why** and **how** this **only affects the export of texture atlases**, and nothing else.

Hope this experience helps someone else in the future...

I will update the bug report at Apple as well.

**UPDATE:** According to Apple, the issue has been solved as of iOS 8 beta 2 (Build 12A4297e). I haven't had an opportunity to check (the project I was working at was a prototype that didn't take off, and I settled for the name change solution). In any case, iOS 8 is final now.